# Ortho projection of 3D points with a vector

Tags: ios, math, geometry

I have 3D points and I need to make an 2D orthographic projection of them onto a plane that is defined by the origin and a normal `n`. The meaning of this is basically *looking at the points from the top (given the vertical vector)*. How can I do it?

What I'm thinking is:

1. project point P onto the 3D plane: `P - P dot n * n`
2. look at the 3D plane from the "back" in respect to the normal (not sure how to define this)
3. do an ortho projection using max-min coordinates of the points in the plane to define the clipping

I am working with iOS.

Comment: The `P - P dot n * n` should be sufficient for projecting the points onto the plane. Maybe I'm missing something?

Comment: @eigenchris I need to have the 2D coordinate system lying on that plane so that I can compare x and y coordinates of points

Comment: I understand. I'll write up an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this would be to:

1. rotate the coordinate system so that the plane of interest lies in the x-y plane, and the normal vector `n` is aligned with the z-axis
2. project the points onto the x-y plane by setting their z-components to `0`

---

**Set up the coordinate transformation**

There are infinitely many solutions to this problem since we can always rotate a solution in the x-y plane to get another valid solution.

To fix this, let's choose a vector `v` lying in the plane that will line up with the x-axis after the transformation. Any vector will do; let's take the vector in the plane with coordinates `x=1` and `y=0`.

Since our plane intersects the origin, its equation is:

```
x*n1 + y*n2 + z*n3 = 0
z = -(x*n1 + y*n2)/n3
```

After substituting `x=1`, `y=0`, we see that

```
v = [1 0 -n1/n3]
```

We also need to make sure `v` is normalized, so set

```
v = v/sqrt(v1*v1 + v2*v2 + v3*v3)
```

**EDIT**: The above method will fail in cases where `n3=0`. An alternative method to find `v` is to take a random point `P1` from our point set that is **not** a scalar multiple of `n` and calculate `v = P1 - P1 dot n * n`, which is the projection of `P1` into the plane. Just keep searching through your points until you find one that satisfies `(P1 dot n/norm(n)) != P1` and this is guaranteed to work.

Now we need a vector `u` that will line up with the y-axis after the transformation. We get this from the cross product of `n` and `v`:

```
u = n cross v
```

If `n` and `v` are normalized, then `u` is automatically normalized.

Next, create the matrix

```
M = [ v1 v2 v3 ]
    [ u1 u2 u3 ]
    [ n1 n2 n3 ]
```

**Transform the points**

Now given a 3 by N array of points `P`, we just follow the two steps above

1. `P_transformed = M*P`
2. `P_plane = set the third row of P_transformed to zero`

The x-y coordinates of `P_plane` are now a 2D coordinate system in the plane.

If you need to get the 3D spatial coordinates back, just do the reverse transformation with `P_space = M_transpose*P_plane`.

Comment: Is `v` the equivalent of an _up_ vector?

Comment: @aledalgrande `v` and `u` are the coordinate axes for the plane. You can think of them as the new `x` and `y` axes inside the plane. I'm not sure what you mean by *up vector*.

Comment: I see, you went for a different way of what I had in my head. Thanks!

Comment: @aledalgrande No problem. You could also use `P - P dot n * n` first and *then* transform, but the set-to-zero method after the transformation method is simpler.

Comment: One question, what if the normal is [0 -1 0]?

Comment: @aledalgrande That's a very good point; we'll get a division-by-zero error there. I'll try to think of a general solution that overcomes this problem.

Comment: @aledalgrande One way to fix this problem is to grab a random point `P1`, and calculate `v = P1 - P1 dot n * n`. As long as `P1` is not a scalar multiple of `n`, this is guaranteed to work. I'll edit my answer to include this.